# php: match specific word with same word from string and remove it

Tags: php

string example.

```
$val = "Olympus Stylus VG-165 mp";
```

i am trying to remove mp from string

Result: `Olyus Stylus VG-165.`

it remove 'mp' from end of string and also from olympus.

how can i remove mp from end, but nor from olympus

Desire ouput:`Olympus Stylus VG-165.`

Comment: you can use substr and give it a position

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple single line

```
echo substr("Olympus Stylus VG-165 mp",0,22);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = preg_replace('# mp$#',' ',$var) ; // Remove if there is " mp" at the end
$var = preg_replace('#^mp #',' ',$var) ; // Remove if "mp " on start
$var = preg_replace('# mp #',' ',$var) ; // Remove if " mp " everywhere
$var = trim($var) ; // Remove the extras space on start and end of the string
```

An other way to make it :

```
function testMp($v) { return $v != 'mp' ; } // Function called by array_filter
$words = explode(' ',$var) ; // Explode the words of the string in an array
$words = array_filter($words,'testMp') ; // Test each word on the array and remove if "mp" found (via testMp)
$var = implode(' ',$words) ; // Restore the words array into a simple string
```

Comment: if mp is in center then.